# How to add a diagram in OO Writer

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-writer

I would like to insert a diagram in OpenOffice Writer. Is there a toolbar to do it from Writer, or I would have to create it in OpenOffice Draw and then somehow add it to Writer. I also want to edit a diagram whenever need, so I am looking for an answer how to do it from Writer :)

If I have to do it using OpenOffice Draw
- can i paste it?
- do i need to save it as a file and then import it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two toolbars to insert and edit drawing elements in writer: **`Drawing`** and **`Drawing Object Properties`**. You can toggle them using Menu **`View`** -> **`Toolbars`**.

[image]

If you need more functionality, you can embed a Draw document using **`Insert`** -> **`Object`** -> **`OLE Object`**.